# Match list of strings with a block of text

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzy-search

Beginner here:

I have a block of text:

For example: `'hey this is a block of text, for an example, wow looks cool blah blah blah angiotensin enzyme looks cool okay.But what about angiotensin enzym well I dont know.'`

and a list of words: `['angiotensin enzyme serum', 'some diff enzyme', 'angiotensin enzyme a1']`

My end goal is to find from the list of words which string matches/fuzzy matches from the block of text.

What have I tried: `difflib.get_close_matches`

Output Required: `'angiotensin enzyme serum'`, `'angiotensin enzyme a1'`

Output order isnt a concern.

For other blocks of text, some other string from list would match. Block isnt constant.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fuzzywuzzy` (from PyPi):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

text = 'hey this is a block of text, for an example, wow looks cool blah blah blah angiotensin enzyme looks cool okay.But what about angiotensin enzym well I dont know.'

words = ['angiotensin enzyme serum', 'some diff enzyme', 'angiotensin enzyme a1']

matches = [w for w in words if fuzz.partial_ratio(text, w) > 70.]
```

Obviously you will want to adjust the threshold value to suit, but the values are well separated in this example:

```
>>> print(matches)
['angiotensin enzyme serum', 'angiotensin enzyme a1']

>>> for w in words:
...     print(w, fuzz.partial_ratio(text, w))
... 
angiotensin enzyme serum 83
some diff enzyme 56
angiotensin enzyme a1 90
```